# Unable to configure settings of second router added to network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I am trying to add a new router (NETGEAR WNDR3800) to my network that currently only has an existing modem/router combo from my provider. I tried using the following configuration:
[first modem router configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Y3QX.png) However, the in this configuration the WiFi network has no internet.

Once I tried connecting it like so, the NETGEAR router's network worked well:
[second modem router configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LG18f.png)

So now I have two separate WiFi networks with two different names and passwords. I would like to change the new NETGEAR router WiFi to match the network of the other, but I am unable to actually open the settings of the NETGEAR router (they should be under [www.routerlogin.net](http://www.routerlogin.net) according to the manual but when I go there it redirects me to a page saying I'm not connected to any NETGEAR routers).

On tutorials online I read that I will need to turn off my main router, connect the NETGEAR router and change the IP and DHCP settings, but my main router receives internet via a phone cable and [the NETGEAR router doesn't have this socket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLDq8.png). What can I do?

Comment: It appears setup 1 is network to WAN and setup 2 is network to LAN which is normally preferable to me. See if you can determine what your network IP is and your Netgear IP is. Then try last digit .1 t o log into your Netgear. If need b, disconnect it and try again setting it up. Last question, your modem should have an Ethernet port regardless of having a Phone WAN connection.

Comment: the router shouldn't need internet access in order to login and set the IP/DHCP settings. so there shouldn't be any reason that you would either need to have the internet router on or to plug your internet cable into the second router. you only need to turn the internet router off for a few minutes while you complete the configuration on the second router so that its part of your existing IP network. then you can turn the internet back on.

Answer (score 0):

1. Setup the ISP router/modem as they tell you to.
   Turn off any WiFi completely
2. Setup the Netgear as a "computer" receiving(?) ONE IP from 1.
3. Setup the Netgear (DHCP!) to provide IP:s to your local / LAN devices;
   make them be from from 10.0.0.z (z = 1 to 254) if 2. has an IP starting from
   192.168.x.y, or vice versa.
   Use WiFi in any manner you wish.

*This is the way my WNDR 4300 was setup some time ago.*

This way; the ONLY thing you need to change is 2. if you move from one apartment/house or even just ISP to another.